# How to decode space and Chinese character

Tags: android, decode, android-c2dm

My server send message through c2dm server
Original msg: This is a string containing 中文 character

But when i receive the message in my android app
Receive: This+is+a+string+containing+%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87+character

How to decode the message?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct the response string with UTF-8.Have you tried this?

Answer (score 1):

try this online url decoder
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/